# Provider/Home realm discovery in B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We have an Azure AD B2C instance which is configured with 2 providers:

- AAD
- custom OIDC

I am using this sample SPA: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp

That sample has following login procedure:

```
function login() {
  clientApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken) {
    clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
      updateUI();
    }, function (error) {
      clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
        updateUI();
      }, function (error) {
        logMessage("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
      });
    })
  }, function (error) {
    logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
  });
}
```

This is what can happen in the application:

1. User presses the login button. The login pop-up will be shown.
2. User logs in with his AAD account.
3. Application tries to acquire token silently for the current AAD
   user. This fails and a pop-up window will be shown.
4. User logs in with custom OIDC account.

In this situation the AAD user is logged in (id_token) but the access_token represents the custom OIDC user.

I have tried

```
clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(
  applicationConfig.b2cScopes,
  applicationConfig.authority,
  clientApplication.getUser(),
  { 'prompt': 'none' }
).then(...);
```

but did not worked. It presents the list of the providers to choose from.

How can I achieve that acquireTokenPopup will redirect me to AAD without home realm discovery/provider discovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in the parameter "domain_hint" and set the value to the value that you provided in the AAD technical profile for

Comment: That helped thanks, but how do I read out the `idp` claim from the raw `idToken`? The `Msal.Utils.extractIdToken(idToken).idp` is not intended to use. They are hidden from documentation. I would expect something like `clientApplication.getUser().token.idp` but there is no publicly available code for reading claims of the logged in user(s). Do I have to switch to another library?